# Extract .war in linux server machine

Tags: linux, shell, spring-boot

I have following line in my start.sh file.

```
unzip -c /opt/myFolder/TEST/bin/TEST.war META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

In Linux command window[using putty] went to the particular folder[/opt/myFolder/TEST/bin].

Started start.sh file using **./start.sh** command.

I can see following lines in my console.

```
7374 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
  inflating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: TEST
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: prasathm
Implementation-Vendor-Id: TEST
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.4.2.RELEASE
Implementation-Vendor: Pivotal Software, Inc.
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
Start-Class: com.mytest.Application
Spring-Boot-Classes: WEB-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: WEB-INF/lib/
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_25
Implementation-URL: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/TEST/
```

Where can I see extracted files? 
After extract I need to run **com.mytest.Application** class

Or How do I extract & run Springboot war file in linux server ?

Comment: if you need to run a springboot application, it should be a jar app. If you want to run the war, you need to deploy it to a servlet container like tomcat.

Comment: So instead of packing into war, we need to pack that into jar & run the main class.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot applications contain everything to run by them self. So you don't need to build a war and deploy it. You only need to run the jar. This jar contains everything.

In order to run the jar you need to

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

you can see more here

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html

Comment: Ok let me try this.